# SSRS - Multiple parameters from different datasets in a single report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have 2 data-sets coming from different stored procedures , have different fields and different parameters .

I want to use parameters from both data sets in a single report but after trying I don't think this is valid .

What is the best practice for doing that ?

Comment: That will work fine.  Parameters aren't tied to datasets, except that a Parameter may get a list of possible values from a Dataset.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried 'Get values from query' option? Or else, subreports?